# Is it possible to show progress for ARM deployment in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps. After building and testing stuff, I create Azure Resources in order to deploy the app there.

I use **Azure Resource Group Deployment** task for that. It works, but in logs I see only this (for all the resouces I created):

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: Create Azure Resources
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure Resource Group Deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure resource manager (ARM) template to a resource group. You can also start, stop, delete, deallocate all Virtual Machines (VM) in a resource group
Version      : 2.147.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/argtaskreadme)
==============================================================================
Checking if the following resource group exists: awesomeApp42.
Resource group exists: true.
Creating deployment parameters.
The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\1\s\arm-template.json' is 'utf-8'
Starting Deployment.
Deployment name is awesomeApp42.
Successfully deployed the template.
##[section]Finishing: Create Azure Resources
```

Is it possible to get any details on that? E.g. what resources were created, with what names and when?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, according to [the schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops). But you can always use Azure Powershell task to achieve that, something like:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Verbose ...
```

so basically add `-Verbose` switch to your `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet. Pretty sure this is the closest you can get

Comment: Wait a minute, you can write deployment-output into a variable by using the 'deploymentOutputs' field of the task and later output this variable

Comment: i supposed he needs a live feed, not the outputs, since output do not provide timestamps, output only provide whatever you specify and no timestampls @D.J.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use the Azure portal to view deployment details independently of the script output:

1. Open the page for the Resource Group that the deployment is in. (One way is to type "Resource Groups" into the portal search bar.)
2. On the Resource Group page, click **Deployments** in the Settings group.
3. Click your deployment and then for the operation of interest, **Operation details**.